# How do I add a lot of data to a shapefile in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-table

I have some nice shapefiles from Agesic in Uruguay, I need to add to them some information (not as shapefile) that I got from Dinamige to the attribute table. These institution are not the point, the point is that I have a lot of new information to add to the shapefiles.

I was able to add new columns, they look very nice and empty, so I want to copy and paste the new information there and not write it one by one. I have just one attribute that is the same, all the other stuff is new information. The thing is I'm a new QGIS user and I don't understand how Python Console works, that is like out of my league. I was searching someone with the same problem but I don´t find it. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: To supply an answer I need to know what format the data you want to import is in? is it an excel or a vector format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a common attribute in both the existing .SHP and the "file" (lets call it a .csv) I use the attribute join feature either as part of QGIS or the mmqgis plug in. That is how I do what you are wanting to do when I want to append sales data to residential properties in a DCDB.

Also this process can take a long time i.e press go and come back in a day so if someone has a quicker solution I would love to know also. These processes above do not allow you to quantify how successful the process was. It just writes the results to a new .shp file.

Comment: The data I want to import is a .txt, I imported in excel. It has no spatial data.

Comment: Yeahhh!!! It worked!! It seems like magic to me ;) Thank you a lot!! Cool, you made my work rock!

Comment: No Problem glad to be of assistance :-)